# What digits appear in 2,3,6,1,8,6,8,4,8,4,8...?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence begins: $2,3,6,1,8,6,8,4,8,4,8....$

(See [OEIS A093095](http://oeis.org/A093095).)

$2*3=6; 
3*6=1,8;
6*1=6;
1*8=8;
8*6=4,8;$
and so on.

Will there ever be a $5$? Will the sequence ever repeat?

I tried doing this by hand, and so far the only numbers I have are $1,2,3,4,6,8$: none of which can be multiplied together to get a $5$.

Which digits never occur? How does one prove this in general?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are always taking the product of single digit numbers, you might want to pull out a multiplication table:
[image: Multiplication Table]
Almost the only time $m*n$ for $m,n$ single digits produces a $0, 5, 7$ or $9$ is when one (or both) of $m$ and $n$ includes a $0, 5, 7$ or $9$.

The one exception is $3*3 = 9$, but no single digit numbers multiply to give $33$.

Using this reasoning, suppose one of those four digits appeared. In fact, consider the *first* time one of those digits appeared. Then it must have been preceded by one of those digits, which contradicts its *firstness*.

Thus, $0, 5, 7$ and $9$ never appear in this sequence.

Comment: Thank you!
I had never heard of OEIS until now.

Comment: I did awhile ago.